# Compartir articulo a WhatsApp mediante WebView

Tags: android

me gustaría si es posible me puedan orientar y decirme el porqué me figura un error al momento de compartir un articulo por WhatsApp y que lo estoy visualizando en un webview, me aparece un error **net::ERR_UNKNOWn_SCHEME**

Comment: Rodrigo agrega tu código html para revisar como tratas de abrir Whatsapp

Answer (score 2):

El esquema que tienes definido en tu página web para abrir Whatsapp no puede ser reconocido por eso el error:

> ERR_UNKNOWN_SCHEME

El [Custom URL scheme](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-custom-url-schemes) que debe estar definido en tu página web debe ser:  **`whatsapp://send?text=`**, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=StackOverflow%20es%20Excelente!">Envia el mensaje: StackOverflow es Excelente!</a>
```

Con esto al dar clic, abrirá la aplicación, te requerirá un contacto y podrás enviar el mensaje deseado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]